# customize emacs mode and font-lock-defaults

Tags: emacs, font-lock

I am writing a minor mode for HTML/PHP templates.

I have a var with PHP keywords

```
(defvar web-mode-php-keywords
 '("array" "as" "break" "catch" "continue")
  "PHP keywords.")
```

This var is used for font-locking like this :

```
(defvar web-mode-php-font-lock-keywords
 (list
  (cons (concat "\\<\\(" (regexp-opt web-mode-php-keywords) "\\)\\>") 'web-mode-keyword-face)
...
```

I don't manage to find out a way to let a user add a keyword to the `web-mode-php-keywords` list in his `.emacs`

`web-mode-php-font-lock-keywords` relies on `web-mode-php-keywords` and trying to alter `web-mode-php-keywords` in a hook doesn't work because `web-mode-php-font-lock-keywords` is already built

I think I miss something ... 
(is this related to `eval-after-load` ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do `(setq web-mode-php-keywords '("array" "as" "break" "catch" "continue" "mykeyword1" "mykeyword2"...))` *before* loading the web-mode file.

Comment: I wan't to let users add keywords not set all keyords list. I've done this : `(defconst web-mode-php-constants
  (eval-when-compile
    (regexp-opt
     (append (if (boundp 'web-mode-php-constants) web-mode-php-constants '())
             '("TRUE" "FALSE" "NULL" "true" "false" "null"))))
  "PHP constants.")` .... but perhaps a better solution exists